# Лишние запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Казалось, что кричали эти самые юноши, но(,) кроме меня, это(,) похоже(,) никого не волновало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удивительно! Все запятые, как ни странно, расставлены абсолютно верно, так что можете даже не сомневаться в правильности Вашего предложения.

Если Вас интересует более детальное объяснение, то я попробую истолковать.

1. Слово *кроме*, если находится внутри, выделяется с двух сторон. 
   Это - точно не знаю - кажется, обособление дополнения. Данная конструкция эквивалента словосочетанию *за исключением*, которая, находясь внутри, выделяется с двух сторон запятыми. 
   Пример:

> Все, кроме Жени, знали французский язык на довольно-таки должном уровне. Все информационные сообщества, за исключением "Цукерберг позвонит", имеют корректора.

1. *Похоже* - вводное слово, которое выделяется с двух сторон, если находится внутри предложения. Данное слово имеет значение *кажется, наверное, по-видимому*.

Запятые при вводных словах могут быть расставлены по-разному. Примеры:

> Кажется, Женя плохо понимал такой термин, как мини-игры. 
> Женя, по-видимому, не знает, кто живёт рядом с ним.

Как видите, в моих примерах вводное слово находится в разных позициях.

Надеюсь, у меня получилось грамотно объяснить Вам пунктуацию данного предложения.

Comment: Да, спасибо!

Comment: @Tagirix, а вас удивило?

Answer (score 0):

Запятые расставлены верно.

Answer (score 0):

**но() кроме меня()...** - здесь запятые не нужны.